# eclipse could not find main class

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java program that has 3 classes and an .aj file. I have my main named Main.class.

When I'm trying to run my program it says it could not find my main class, even though it's right there.

[image: java]

Comment: Why is your `package prob1;` commented? Does your class even compile without this line?

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is trying to `run` `prob1.Main` which doesnt exist. By looking at your class you `commented` the `package` name. Try recompiling your class again and `run` it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't comment out the:

```
  package prob1;
```

The only time you don't need to write the package is when you are using the default package for a project (which is created automatically when you create a class in a new project). Edit the code snippet and then run the program again and it should be fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

SomeTimes eclipse get corrupted run configuration......
For that issue three solution is  there

1. Go to Run configuration setting ,
   inside JAva Apllication you find your project,
   click on that,
   on right panel re-path you main class file path
2. if 1st doesn't work,take a backup of your main class ,delete it and re create new main class ,and copy the code from back up
3. if 2nd failed .Close eclipse.
   Delete the .metadata directory.
   Start eclipse.
   Import the projects.
   Run the project again.